# There is a typo in tour

Tags: bug, status-completed

There is a typo in site's tour

```
Questions seeking seeking uncommon solutions to common problems
```

Seeking is written twice

Comment: That's a great find!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for noticing, Aseem! I've [fixed it](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/tour), so now there's only 1 'seeking'.